# What norm makes $C^\infty[a,b]$ a complete space?

Tags: normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I have been searching for some common norms used on vector spaces of functions but I am not having any luck finding what the most common norm is to use on $C^\infty[a,b]$ More specifically I would like to find a norm that makes that space complete. Does such a norm exist?

Also what are some good resources that deal with spaces of functions, preferably at an advanced undergraduate or beginner graduate level?

Comment: why do you think $C^\infty$ is normable?

Comment: Well to be honest I don't really know to much about norms, so I hadn't even thought of the possibility that you can't place a norm on $C^\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would make it a Frechet space, by using the countable collection of seminorms given by taking the supremum of each derivative.

I.e. define $s_n(f)$ to be the sup of $f^{(n)}$ on $[a,b]$, and consider the
weakest topology for which all the $s_n$ are continuous.  This makes $C^{\infty}[a,b]$ a Frechet space.

This is the natural topology to use, in that a sequence of functions converges
iff the sequence of $n$th derivatives converges uniformly for each $n$.  As far as I know it can't be described by a single norm.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that you couldn't put a single norm on $C^\infty$ but the seminorm idea makes sense (It seems I need to read some more)

Comment: @Twiltie: Dear Twiltie, Books on locally convex vector spaces (e.g. Bourbaki's *Topological vector spaces*, or the shortish CUP book by Robinson and Robinson with a similar name) will discuss this example, but perhaps surrounded by more foundational abstraction than you might want.  Books on distributions (probably more old-fashioned ones, at least) will also discuss it.  One basic thing to remember is that to guarantee that a uniform limit of differentiable functions is again differentiable, you need to assume that the derivatives converge as well.  (This is a standard theorem form real ...

Comment: ... analysis books.)  So to get a nice topological structure on $C^{\infty}$, you are more-or-less forced to use the whole collection of seminorms $s_n$.  Cheers,